# Concat and remove some json elements based on key in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON array object which has a property `id` with several entry and each entry has some more property. I want to merge these object on the basis of this `id` and delete the redundant data. Also same id value will be adjacent to each other. Look below data to understand more :

```
var obj = [  {"Id":13075121312, "p1":"R"}
            ,{"Id":13075121312, "p2":"R"}
            ,{"Id":13075121312, "p3":"R"}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p1":"R",}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p2":"R",}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p3":"R",}
        ] ;
```

I need to convert this array of object as following :

```
var obj = [  {"merchantId":13075121312, "p1":"R", "p2":"R", "p3":"R"}
            ,{"merchantId":9160507252, "p1":"R", "p2":"R", "p3":"R"}
        ] ;
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried the following function it is not working :

```
function jsonConcat(obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length-1; ){
        if(obj[i]['d'] === obj[i+1]['Id']){
            obj[i]['Id'] = obj[i+1]['Id'];
            delete json[obj[i+1]];
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var obj = [  {"Id":13075121312, "p1":"R"},{"Id":13075121312, "p2":"R"},{"Id":13075121312, "p3":"R"},{"Id":9160507252, "p1":"R"},{"Id":9160507252, "p2":"R"},{"Id":9160507252, "p3":"R"}];
        
obj = Object.values(obj.reduce((a,{Id, ...rest}) => {
  a[Id] = a[Id] || {merchantId:Id};
  Object.assign(a[Id], rest);
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This works like charm. Also i think for this same id need not to be consecutive. Thanks :)

Comment: @AtulKumar - Glad to help you! Yes, your understanding is correct. Id need not to be consecutive.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, can you explain the complexity of above function and overall computation cost ?

Comment: @AtulKumar - Time complexity will be linear in the above solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [**`Spread in object literals`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

```js
var obj = [  {"Id":13075121312, "p1":"R"}
             ,{"Id":13075121312, "p2":"R"}
            ,{"Id":13075121312, "p3":"R"}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p1":"R",}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p2":"R",}
            ,{"Id":9160507252, "p3":"R",}
        ] 
        
let result = [];
obj.forEach(a => {
  let same = result.findIndex(b => b.Id === a.Id);
  if(same > -1) result[same] = {...result[same],...a};
  else result.push(a);
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use for loop to iterate over array then set unique id on object as an property and update that object property when same is found.

```
var obj = [  {"Id":13075121312, "p1":"R"}
                ,{"Id":13075121312, "p2":"R"}
                ,{"Id":13075121312, "p3":"R"}
                ,{"Id":9160507252, "p1":"R",}
                ,{"Id":9160507252, "p2":"R",}
                ,{"Id":9160507252, "p3":"R",}
            ] ;

    var newObj = {};
    for(var i = 0;i < obj.length; i++) {
       var item = obj[i];
        if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(item['Id'])) { newObj[item['Id']] = {};}
        newObj[item['Id']] = {'merchantId':item['Id'], ...newObj[item['Id']], ...item};  
    }

    var val = Object.values(newObj);
    console.log(val);
```